# How to demonstrate that the class of ordinal numbers is isomorphic to the class of initial ordinal ones?

Tags: number-theory, set-theory, ordinals

In the 11th chapter of the book *Set theory for the mathematicians* by Jean E. Rubin I've read that: $\omega_\alpha = \omega_\beta \iff \alpha = \beta$ and $\omega_\alpha < \omega_\beta \iff \alpha < \beta$. I've already tried to demonstrate that through transfinite induction, but, apart from the most banal cases, it seems complicated: can someone help me by any chance?

However I think we can proceed in this way

First of all we remember that through transfinite induction it's easily possible to demonstrate that $\omega_\alpha<\omega_{\alpha+1}$.

Then we observe that if it's $0=\alpha< \beta \Rightarrow \omega = \omega_0 = \omega_\alpha < \omega_\beta$, one could try to demonstrate that through transfinite induction; so we suppose that $\forall \gamma < \beta$ | $\alpha < \gamma \Rightarrow \omega_\alpha < \omega_\gamma$

$\begin{cases}\alpha < \beta=(\overline\gamma + 1)\ \\ \alpha < \beta=\bigcup_{\gamma<{\beta}}\gamma \ \end{cases}\Rightarrow \begin{cases}\alpha\le\overline\gamma \rightarrow\begin{cases}\alpha<\overline\gamma \\ \alpha=\overline\gamma\end{cases} \\ \alpha = \overline\gamma < (\overline\gamma + 1)\le\bigcup_{\gamma<{\beta}}\gamma=\beta\ \end{cases}\Rightarrow\begin{cases} \omega_\alpha<\omega_{\overline\gamma} < \omega_{\overline\gamma+1}=\omega_\beta  \\ \omega_\alpha=\omega_{\overline\gamma}<\omega_{\overline\gamma+1}=\omega_\beta \\ \omega_\alpha=\omega_{\overline\gamma}<\omega_{\overline\gamma+1}\le\bigcup_{\gamma<\beta}\omega_\gamma=\omega_\beta  \end{cases}\Rightarrow\omega_\alpha<\omega_\beta$

Then -trivially- if $\alpha=\beta\Rightarrow\omega_\alpha=\omega_\beta$, we observe that if $\omega_\alpha=\omega_\beta$ it's also $\alpha=\beta$,
since if it were $\alpha\neq\beta$, as far as proved, it would be $\omega_\alpha<\omega_\beta$ or $\omega_\beta<\omega_\alpha$ and it's impossible.

What do you think about this demonstration?

Comment: Transfinite induction is right, and there are exactly three banal cases. $0$, successor, limit.

Comment: Hi! I think that I've found an another demonstration: read above. Do you think it's correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is relatively easy to establish that the property bellow holds for all ordinals $\beta$ by transfinite induction on $\beta$ :

$$P(\beta) := \forall \alpha \in \operatorname{Ord}, \left\{ \begin{array}{ccc} \alpha < \beta & \Longrightarrow & \omega_\alpha < \omega_{\beta} \\ 
\alpha > \beta & \Longrightarrow & \omega_\alpha > \omega_{\beta} \end{array} \right.$$
**Edit** : Simplified $P$.

Clearly, $P(0)$ holds.

Let $0 \neq \beta \in \operatorname{Ord}$, assume $P(\beta')$ holds for every $\beta' < \beta$.

- **successor** : assume $\beta = \gamma + 1$. Then one has $\omega_\gamma < \omega_\beta$ since $\omega_\beta = \omega_\gamma^{\ +}$.
  Let $\alpha \in \operatorname{Ord}$.
  $\qquad$ Clearly, if $\alpha < \gamma$, one has $\omega_\alpha < \omega_\beta$.
  $\qquad$ If $\alpha = \gamma$, then $\omega_\alpha = \omega_\gamma < \omega_\beta$.
  $\qquad$ What remains is the case $\alpha > \beta$, we show that $\omega_\alpha > \omega_\beta$ by transfinite induction on $\alpha$, starting with $\alpha = \beta + 1$.

> **proof that $\alpha > \beta \Rightarrow \omega_\alpha > \omega_\beta$ :**
>   Assume $\alpha = \beta + 1$, then $\omega_{\alpha} = \omega_{\beta}^{\ +} > \omega_\beta$
>   Assume $\alpha = \kappa + 1$, where $\omega_\kappa> \omega_\beta$, then $\omega_\alpha = \omega_\kappa^{\ +} > \omega_\kappa > \omega_\beta$.
>   Assume $\alpha$ is a limit ordinal, then $\omega_\alpha = \bigcup_{\kappa < \alpha} \omega_\kappa \geqslant \omega_{\beta + 1} > \omega_\beta$ since $\alpha > \beta + 1$.

- **limit** : Here, $\omega_\beta = \bigcup_{\kappa < \beta} \omega_\kappa$.
  Let $\alpha < \beta$. Since $\beta$ is limit, we also have $\alpha + 1 < \beta$. Hence, $\omega_\alpha < \omega_{\alpha + 1} \leqslant \bigcup_{\kappa < \beta} \omega_\kappa = \omega_\beta$.
  Let $\alpha > \beta$, then we get $\omega_\alpha > \omega_\beta$ as above.

Comment: Could you please explain me why if ∀β′ < β, ∀α ∈ Ord result that $\alpha$ > $\beta$ ⟹ $\omega_\alpha > \omega_{\beta^{'}}$, so it must be $\omega_\alpha > \omega_\beta$?

Comment: Then I think that the case $\alpha < \beta^{'}$ it's strange because it's impossible to chose $\beta^{'}$ = $0$ and this is necessary to apply transifinite induction.

Comment: @AntonioMariaDiMauro Yes it is possible, if $\beta' = 0$, the statement $\forall \alpha < \beta', \, \omega_\alpha < \omega_{\beta'}$ is a tautology.

Comment: @AntonioMariaDiMauro Alright, my setup wasn't perfect but I hope this proof convinces you.

Comment: Hi! I think that I've found an another demonstration: read above. Do you think it's correct?

Comment: You only need the first case for $P$. Then if $\alpha<\beta$ then the $\beta$th step of the induction guarantees that $\omega_\alpha<\omega_\beta$.